# How do you assign requestModels to a METHOD AWS API Gateway Documentation Part?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I'm trying to generate an openAPI Schema from AWS API Gateway.  To do this I'm uploading an openAPI 3.0.3 schema augmented with `x-amazon-apigateway-documentation`.

The documentation around this seems to be very lacking and I can't seem to associate a requestModel with a METHOD documentation part.

A very simplified openAPI document looks like this:

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.3",
  "info": {},
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Sends an email to the user",
        "description": "Sends an email to the user with a PDF",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TPComparisonRequest" }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "TPComparisonRequest": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "x-amazon-apigateway-documentation": {
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "documentationParts": [
      { "location": { "type": "RESOURCE", "path": "/" }, "properties": {} },
      {
        "location": { "type": "MODEL", "name": "TPComparisonRequest" },
        "properties": {
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "location": {
          "type": "METHOD",
          "path": "/",
          "method": "post"
        },
        "properties": {
          "summary": "Sends an email to the user",
          "description": "Sends an email to the user with a PDF",
          "requestModels": { "application/json": "TPComparisonRequest" }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now when I save this to a file and run `aws apigateway import-documentation-parts --rest-api-id restAPIId --body fileb://openAPI.json`

it'll generate me the documentationParts:

[image: Screenshot of the generated METHOD Documentation Part in AWS API Gateway]
[image: Screenshot of the generated MODEL Documentation Part in AWS API Gateway]

However, when I go to export this from the Documentation tab on AWS API Gateway, the generated OpenAPI file does not include a `requestBody`:

```json
{
  "openapi" : "3.0.1",
  "paths" : {
    "/" : {
      "post" : {
        "summary" : "Sends an email to the user",
        "description" : "Sends an email to the user with a PDF"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So how do you assign requestBody to the documentationPart so that it'll generate a similar openAPI file that is fed into it?

I've kept the openAPI file short for brevity, but if you'd prefer more detail I can provide a longer openAPI example.